# The best overloaded Method has some invalid arguments and Cannot convert type

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, type-conversion

```
Banking object1 = new Banking(t1.Text);
MessageBox.Show(object1.transact(t2.Text));
```

It's giving an error of invalid arguments in the method and also that it cant convert from String to float.
`Banking` is the class and `object1` is an object, transact is a method.
As long as I believe there is no error in the method still below I'm pasting my class and method code:

```
class Banking
    {   string bankName;
        float amount;

        public Banking(string name)
        {
            bankName = name;
        }
        public string transact(float a)
        {
            amount = a * 7 / 100;
            float total =Convert.ToSingle(amount + a);
            return "Your amount of Rupees : " + total + "has been deposited in " + bankName;
        }
    }
```

Here is the error list:

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Banking.transact(float)' has some invalid arguments.

---

> Error  2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'float'

Comment: What do you understand to be the type of `t2.Text`? What do you understand to be the type of the parameter of `transact`? Do you expect there to be an implicit conversion from the first type to the second?

Comment: As the error message is telling you `Banking.Transact()` wants a `float` passed as an argument. You're passing `t2.Text`, which if you mouse over `Text` you'll see is a string. In most cases you cannot just arbitrarily convert one type (string) to another (float). You'll have to do some conversion. In most cases you can google something like `C# convert X to Y` and find an example if you can't figure it out on your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb(v=VS.110).aspx) value from string to float.

```
MessageBox.Show(object1.transact(Single.Parse(t2.Text)));
```

Comment: It works, Thank you so much, I do have a question though, I have tried following as well
//MessageBox.Show(object1.transact(Convert.ToSingle(t2.text));
Is it wrong? if yes, can you please explain

Comment: @MHasanAli,*Convert.ToSingle* does try to convert the value, it does not try to parse (i.e. "read") it. To turn a string like `"12.34e5"` into a number, this string has to be **parsed** (like *Single.Parse*) -- i.e. each single character in the string has to be inspected to calculate the actual numerical value represented by this string. Conversion converts a *value* into another *value*. But strings are not  (numerical) values and thus are not convertible. Strings are just sequences of characters like "Hello world" for example...